# handler.py not executing in HuggingFace Inference Endpoint

Tags: python, huggingface-transformers, huggingface, large-language-model, llama

I created a repo based on Llama 2 7B Pawel1212/Llama-2-7b-chat-hf and added handler.py but it seems it is not used. I added some prints and additional behaviour but but neither see the prints nor the new behaviour.

I created the endpoint as Custom task.

Do you maybe know what can be a reason?